# ANTLR grammar: Boolean literal which can occur as qualified variable name while ignoring whitespace

Tags: antlr4

I am creating an interpreter in Java using ANTLR. I have a grammar which I have been using for a long time and I have built a lot of code around classes generated from this grammar.

In the grammar is 'false' defined as a literal, and there is also definition of variable name which allows to build variable names from digits, numbers, underscores and dots (see the definition bellow).

The problem is - when I use 'false' as a variable name. 
`varName.nestedVar.false`. The rule which marks `false` as falseLiteral takes precedence.

I tried to play with the white spaces, using everything I found on the internet. Solution when I would remove `WHITESPACE : [ \t\r\n] -> channel (HIDDEN);` and use explicit WS* or WS+ in every rule would work for the parser, but I would have to adjust a lot of code in the AST visitors. I try to tell boolLiteral rule that it has to have some space before the actual literal like WHITESPACE* trueLiteral, but this doesn't work when the white spaces are sent to the HIDDEN channel. And again disable it altogether = lot of code rewriting. (Since I often rely on the order of tokens.) I also tried to reorder non-terminals in the literal rule but this had no effect whatsoever.

```
...

literal:
    boolLiteral
    | doubleLiteral
    | longLiteral
    | stringLiteral
    | nullLiteral
    | varExpression
;

boolLiteral:
    trueLiteral | falseLiteral
;
trueLiteral:
    TRUE
;
falseLiteral:
    FALSE
;
varExpression:
    name=qualifiedName ...
;

...

qualifiedName:
    ID ('.' (ID | INT))*

...

TRUE : [Tt] [Rr] [Uu] [Ee];
FALSE : [Ff] [Aa] [Ll] [Ss] [Ee];
ID : (LETTER | '_') (LETTER | DIGIT | '_')* ;
INT : DIGIT+ ;
POINT : '.' ;

...

WHITESPACE : [ \t\r\n] -> channel (HIDDEN);
```

My best bet was to move qualifiedName definition to the lexer lure

```
qualifiedName:
    QUAL_NAME
;

QUAL_NAME: ID ('.' (ID | INT))* ;
```

Then it works for

```
varName.false AND false 
varName.whatever.ntimes AND false
```

Result is correct -> varExpression->quilafiedName on the left-hand side and boolLiteral -> falseLiteral on the right-hand side.
But with this definition this doesn't work, and I really don't know why

```
varName AND false
```

Qualified name without . returns

```
line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'varName AND'
```

Expected solution would be ether enable/disable whitespace -> channel{hiddne} for specific rules only

Tell the boolLiteral rule that it canNOT start start with dot, someting like ~POINT falseLiteral, but I tried this as well and with no luck.

Or get qualifiedName working without dot when the rule is moved to the lexer rule.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
qualifiedName
 : ID ('.' (anyId | INT))*
 ;

anyId
 : ID
 | TRUE
 | FALSE
 ;
```